# How to use tagged intermediate image for final build?

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build

I have created a multi-stage build.

- Stage 1: use node:16.10-alpine to compile sources
- Stage 2: use an alpine nginx image, copy build folder from first stage, move configuration, expose port, add entrypoint.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
# Builder
FROM node:10.16-alpine AS builder

... # Do stuff

# Release
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

... # Do stuff

ENTRYPOINT [ ... ]
```

Pretty straight-forward, I'd say. I know that one you run `docker build -t website:latest .` it will create an intermediate image `<none>`, which is that builder image, which might be used later, if there were no changes to sources or `package.json`.

So, my thought was to tag the `builder` step something like this: `docker build --target builder -t website-builder .` and so that even if the sources change, it will just use the same tag and not (please correct me if I'm wrong) create other  images.

If I run build with `--target` flag first and run build again without it doesn't use the builder.

To summarize:

1. `docker build --target builder -t website-builder .`
   [image: First Step]
2. `docker build -t website:latest .`
   [image: Second Step]

New `<none>` image was created which is the same as `website-builder`.

How can I achieve that the builder image is used by the 'Release' stage and rewritten, if changed? If that can't be done, what's the best-practice in this case? Is there one?

Thanks for sticking through. I appreciate any feedback or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may use:

```
COPY --from=website-builder:latest .....
```

Comment: Oh! This did work! Thank you so much! With this `--from` I'll need a script to build the builder image first and then the actual build. Doesn't this break the idea of a multi-stage build or I'm having a wrong idea about it?

Comment: IMHO  you need to remove the website-builder from your docker file and just use the copy statement in your release dockerfile

Comment: So basically have 2 Dockerfiles, one for the builder and one for the release. Right? The only problem is that the builder image is used _only_ for release. Development happens with a dev server outside docker.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it. Could you, please, share when is it worth using multi-stage builds then?

Comment: it all mentioned here :) https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: Great, thank you! Sorry for picking your brain so much. Have a great day.